# how to include lxml in depenency list of python package with setuptools?

Tags: python, lxml, packaging, setuptools

I have used the following code in setup.py file

```
setup(...,
    install_requires=[       
          'lxml'
      ],
      .....)
```

But when i install the package it gives the following error

```
    Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for lxml
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('lxml')
```

How to make the setup to install lxml library ?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Strange; I see `lxml` right there in `http://pypi.python.org/simple/lxml/`; are you behind a proxy or something that blocks `setuptools` from finding the dependency?

Comment: suppose if some library (third party) is not present in pypi how to add it to install_requires.

Comment: Leave it up to `easyinstall` or `pip` or `zc.buildout` to worry about where to find dependencies. Only list the package names in `install_requires`.

Comment: ya but i am getting this error


Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/yaml/
Couldn't find index page for 'yaml' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for yaml
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('yaml')

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to install [`PyYaml`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyYAML)? There is indeed no package named `yaml` on PyPI, but the `PyYaml` package installs the `yaml` library.

Comment: Thanks Martijn Pieters :-) It works fine.